Is there a way to extrude these faces in a way that the connecting faces stay aligned to the axis?
I have tried extruding then scaling along normals from individual origins, but that doesn't quite do the right thing...

And after extruding and scaling I get this mess:

As you can see, the top of the chest behaves as desired, but the bottom of the chest gets weird angles in it's extrusion, as if I was scaling from the origin, even though I am scaling from individual origins.  I expect this is from it treating the entire selection as the 'individual origin', but idk how to make it work like I want...

I assume you've applied the scale to both objects (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) before you extruded? - You should just need to Alt-E > Extrude along Normals with the pivot point set to Median Point. I'm not sure why you're trying to scale after extruding?  I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via blend-exchange.com following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

@John Eason - Even before reading your comment, I was finding in my own tests that the method you describe doesn't create fully flat facings of each of the object's extruded sides, but rather, bows outward each side's extruded results slightly. I have not been able to figure out how to ensure complete flatness for every side's extrusion, even when scaling along normals. Very frustrating.

@JohnEason I am trying to scale after extruding because when I just extrude it seems to want extrude along the z axis.  I can look into uploading the blend file later.

If you open the bottom-left operation menu after extruding you can check 'Offset Even' which should correct any distortion.

@JohnEason that checkbox along with using alt_E instead of just E fixed it for me.  If you would please write that up in an answer I will gladly accept it as a solution.

I've done a quick mock-up with seperate box and top objects here.
Use the Face > Extrude Along Normals menu or Alt-E > Extrude Along Normals hotkey rather than extruding and scaling.

In my case the extrusions were correct, but if you get distortions you can check the Offset Even checkbox on the bottom-left Operator panel.

Final result

